# placing and compiling a .java file in working directory

Tags: java

just started learning java, i'm looking to save a .java file (TextIO.java) into my working directory. (which file makes up my working directory exactly?)

and then run it through cmd so that Eclipse can use the class.

I tried doing that by saving (and running thru cmd) the file in the folder containing the programs (yah right) i have written already. But Eclipse still cant find the class.

Can i get some help with this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an Eclipse Java project first. The you can copy the file from file system explorer window and paste it on the Eclipse Package Explorer tree. Eclipse projects compile all files in their source folders automatically by default.

The TextIO.java clas you mentioned has a javadoc saying: ... TextIO provides a set of **static** methods for reading and writing text... This means you use it as a toolkit rather than executing as an application. Given TextIO.java and you class TextIOUtilizer are both in the root of your classpath (source folder in Eclipse), here is how you call a TextIO method:

```
public class TextIOUtilizer {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // code
    TextIO.skipBlanks();
    //code
}
```

}

Now you run TextIOUtilizer as a Java application - it has a main method. Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried doing that and i receive the message:

"selection does not contain main type"

When i try to run the TextIO from my eclipse explorer as application i dnt get that option. But i fiddled around and receive the message:

"Error: Main method not found in class TextIO, please define the main method as:    public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application"

Any help is appreciated thx.

Comment: So, there you go - add a main method to your TextIO class: `public static void main(String[] args) { ... }`. If you share your code I can try to help further.

Comment: im working with TextIO.java

http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/source/chapter2/TextIO.java

not sure about how much i can edit that.